# UIView functions similar to Alertview

Tags: iphone

I need to add 3 buttons and one textfield in an alertview.

It is not possible so in the place of alertview i place create a view with 3 buttons and one textfield In the InterfaceBuilder.

Where ever i need this simply i call like

```
additionalView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addsubview:additionalView];
```

it displays fine, It adds over the existing view,thats fine but when ever i click any button or textfield that all are also working.

But i need  additionalview function same as UIAlertview.

How can i done this,can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIView has a property called 'center' which you can set - so you can assign your subview the center of its parent view, which will place it directly in the middle:

```
additionalView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:additionalView];
```

...will display the view in the middle (calculated according to its frame).

Answer (score 0):

@MaheshBabu above answer of lxt's is correct if u wanna add a textfield and 3 buttons in a additionalView ,if u want that view to be at center then u have to give the center to the view to a additionalView

But u wanna do it through a UIAlertView then i suggest u to follow this link..http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

Hope this may help u!!

Comment: Thank u Sudhanshu,But i clearly mention in my question That i need to add one textfield with 3 buttons,Adding 3 buttons is not correct according to UI guidelines.That's why i prefer view

Comment: yes u r right at your end! additionalView will be a better way!